# Bathroom fan drips. How can I stop it?

Tags: bathroom, insulation, attic, bathroom-fixtures

I have been fighting this bathroom fan for years. I rent but do a decent amount of upkeep and improvements as needed.

I replaced the fan about a year ago. It’s a cheap nutone 80cfm fan. The bathroom is about 9’ x 5’ with a small closet attached that is maybe 3’x5’ but the door can be closed.

I used foil tape to seal the edges around the fan housing. I just today replaced the existing flexible exhaust (which wasn’t insulated at all and basically went straight up from the housing to the roof) with a much longer R6 insulated flex hose. I sealed it to the fan really well (and made sure the flap was working properly) and ran it as flat as possible for a good distance before it sloped up the the roof vent.

I also insulated the fan housing in the attic as best I could and surrounded everything with as much insulation as I could.

The thing still drips after a decently long shower. I can’t imagine it’s dripping all the way back down from where the exhaust exits to the roof.

Could it just be condensating on the fan itself inside the bathroom after a while and never making it out of the bathroom? It definitely is doing better than it used to but I can’t imagine I need a stronger fan for such a small bathroom.

The only other thing I can think of is that the flap on the fan side says that it is slightly open by design to allow for heat dissipation when only the light is on (my bathroom doesn’t allow the fan and light to run separate so this isn’t a concern for me). So I could tape a penny or something to the flap to keep it closed but again I struggle to believe it’s condensation coming all the way back through the flap causing the drips.

It also happens regardless of if it’s raining so I know it isn’t water coming in from the roof.

Obviously I can leave the bathroom door open during showers but that isn’t always ideal when I have guests.

TL;DR my bathroom fan drips no matter how well I try to insulate it. Any tips?

Comment: IT sure sounds like condensation...and the fan isn't pushing enough air.  You need to get a bigger, ( more CFM) fan.

Comment: or possibly there's a blockage in the vent?

Comment: When the fan is not running, does it feel cooler than room temp.  Cold air sinks, so a roof vent has that against it.

Comment: How long does the fan run on after a shower (mine is manual, but most have a run on timer)? And how would replacement air get into the bathroom - is there much of a gap under the door? It *might* be enough to run it for longer after a shower, with the door slightly open, to push drier air through the duct after the very wet air